# What does US Debt maturity means?

Tags: government-debt, public-debt

Read the following news article but couldn't figure out what it entails. Will the government need to print money to pay the current the debt? Or will it take on new debt to pay the old debt? More importantly, how will it affect the stock market?

https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/bonds/us-debt-maturing-bond-yields-treasury-bills-federal-reserve-qt-2023-9

Comment: Debt maturity = principal repayment at a fixed date. Debt repayment would be subject to the institutional constraints/remaining debt stock. And your point on the implications for the stock market depend on the interest rate effects. A higher interest rate will likely reduce investment in the stock market (as bonds become more lucrative); and vice versa.